# How do I pass a date to MySQLdb in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, mysql-python, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to do a rather simple SELECT with a date as a variable. But I always end up receiving a datatype error :

```
today = datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())
cur.execute('select nom from agenda,taverniers where agenda.id_t = taverniers.id_t and agenda.thedate = "%s"') %(today)
```

It throws an exception:

```
moncal.py:61: Warning: Incorrect date value: '%s' for column 'thedate' at row 1
cur.execute('select nom from agenda,taverniers where agenda.id_t = taverniers.id_t and agenda.thedate = "%s"') %(today)
(...)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'datetime.date'`
```

My database has data:

```
mysql> select * from agenda
    -> ;
+------+------+------------+
| id_t | id_c | thedate    |
+------+------+------------+
|    3 |    5 | 2015-12-12 |
|    1 |    6 | 2015-12-24 |
+------+------+------------+
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a simple typo. Python expression for string formatting should be like `'%s'%variable` rather then `('%s') % variable`

Specifically, use

```
cur.execute('select nom from agenda,taverniers where agenda.id_t = taverniers.id_t and agenda.thedate = "%s"' % today)
```

Or consider using recommended syntax (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) with `?` placeholders:

```
cur.execute('select nom from agenda,taverniers where agenda.id_t = taverniers.id_t and agenda.thedate = "?"',(today,))
```

Comment: Well I must admit, it wasn't a typo, my python is just very limited. Thanks to you two @Limar and @Rogalski, works like a charm. Funny things is this `aujourdhui = str('%s') %(today)` wasn't causing any error.

Answer (score 1):

Your line with query is basically:

```
cur.execute('QUERY') % (today)
```

It applies `%` operator to `cur.execute('QUERY')` return value, which is integer. Therefore you receive `TypeError` - `long % datetime` is not defined for long type, and you actually want to do `string % something` operation.

To perform string formatting you'll have to move `%` operator to `cur.execute` argument - call it like `cur.execute('QUERY' % today)`.